# Docker ubuntu build fails on ec2

Tags: ubuntu, docker, amazon-ec2

Endevouring to learn more about Docker. Want to do my work on an ec2 instance. Thought this tutorial was a good place to start:
[Docker Basics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html). When I try to build the docker image from the Dockerfile I get errors when running `apt-get update -y`.

Initially thought an unsupported ubuntu release (12.04) was an issue so updated that reference to latest (17.04) and still errors relating to apt-update (below).

Update: I ran the steps on a non-ec2 machine and got a different output at apt-update stage, so something in ec2 configuration is I think interfering with network connectivity.

Any help appreciated. Console output below:

```
ec2 docker build --no-cache -t moikaturns/amazon-ecs-sample .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   363 kB
Step 1/12 : FROM ubuntu:17.04
 ---> bde41be8de8c
Step 2/12 : RUN apt-get update -y
 ---> Running in d8132cda2e2a
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-security/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
 ---> 6aa041d69aec
Removing intermediate container d8132cda2e2a
Step 3/12 : RUN apt-get install -y git curl apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt php5-mysql
 ---> Running in 1b807c9fd593
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package git
E: Unable to locate package curl
E: Unable to locate package apache2
E: Unable to locate package php5
E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php5
E: Unable to locate package php5-mcrypt
E: Unable to locate package php5-mysql
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y git curl apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt php5-mysql' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Contents of /etc/resolve.conf obtained when the Dockerbuild script runs. It is system generated and sourced from the host machine (to which I added the google DNS). The output from the Dockerfile script confirms the contents in the context of the script running:

```
Step 2/13 : RUN cat /etc/resolv.conf
 ---> Running in 68b494d1fcdb
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search eu-west-1.compute.internal
nameserver 172.31.0.2
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Running this on the ec2 instance works but I cannot run it inside the Dockerfile script (because the ubuntu does not come with curl installed and I cannot run apt-get to install anything due to the network issue):

```
ec2 curl ipinfo.io
{
  "ip": "52.17.159.7",
  "hostname": "ec2-52-17-159-7.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
  "city": "Dublin",
  "region": "Leinster",
  "country": "IE",
  "loc": "53.3389,-6.2595",
  "org": "AS16509 Amazon.com, Inc."
}
```

Comment: I suspect your security group is not configured to allow this ec2 instance to talk to the internet. It may also be an issue with IPv6.

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` on your ec2 machine? Also does `curl ipinfo.io` work on your ec2 machine?

Answer (score 3):

Discovered how to get it working by specifying a different network for docker to use/bind to (an alternative named 'host' in contrast to what I believe is the default option 'bridge'). I cannot explain why one worked and the other not as my networking knowledge is not great.

This article prompted me to try it [Docker container networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/). It describes three 'Default networks' created by docker. When invoking docker it's possible to select a specific network to bind to. I assumed 'none' literally means no network. I tried 'bridge' and the same symptoms presented. I tried 'host' and internet connectivity was achieved (apt-get update worked), ergo that answers my question.

Output of the command to list the networks available to docker:

```
ec2 docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
4d37091ae99e        bridge              bridge              local
cab1b88f8084        host                host                local
592bd8b26a6a        none                null                local
```

Specifying a network when running docker build (the --network switch is the key), the output of apt-get update is my evidence the change works:

```
ec2 docker build --network host --no-cache -t moikaturns/amazon-ecs-sample .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 363.5 kB
Step 1/3 : FROM ubuntu:17.04
 ---> bde41be8de8c
Step 2/3 : RUN cat /etc/resolv.conf
 ---> Running in 62447e6613d6
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search eu-west-1.compute.internal
nameserver 172.31.0.2
 ---> 7456dd87e8eb
Removing intermediate container 62447e6613d6
Step 3/3 : RUN apt-get update -y
 ---> Running in 19c5ba6e2a21
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease [89.2 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease [243 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease [89.2 kB]
...
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports/main amd64 Packages [1438 B]
Fetched 24.2 MB in 3s (7702 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
 ---> bcf0a72ac69e
Removing intermediate container 19c5ba6e2a21
Successfully built bcf0a72ac69e
```

Also found this useful from [Amazon Web Services (AWS) EC2 example](https://docs.docker.com/machine/examples/aws/#step-3-run-docker-commands-on-the-instance):

```
docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

Tells docker to launch an interactive bash shell. Network difficulties can be observed interactively rather than running the Dockerfile script. The frustrating thing is it's a minimal ubuntu and basic tools like ping are not installed. Since apt-get install is not working it's possible to install them to try do much investigation.

Specifying the network that works with docker run enables network functionality:

```
docker run --network=host -it ubuntu bash
```

Thanks to all whom responded to my question.

**RCA**: after following this up with aws a representative kindly assisted in diagnosing what was wrong (the tutorial works fine on a vanilla ec2 instance). Cause was traced to an iptables rule I'd added to my ec2 instance:

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

It redirects inbound port 80 to internal port 8080. Clearly it had upset iptables entries created by Docker(somehow). If I remove this rule the vanilla tutorial works on my ec2 instance (all the iptables rule was doing was routing port 80 to 8080, which I can do using a proxy such as nginx instead).

Comment: I'm facing similar issue in EC2 with RHEL VM. specifying the host network also does not work! Yum install works on the host but not in the docker build.